# How to Add Colormap, OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, colormap

The `Open CV` color map is fixed. (`C++`)

But I need a new color.

What I want is blue to white, with red in between, and the higher temperature is yellow
I want the color of Thermal, As shown in the picture below .

[image]

How do I add a color map?

Any Suggestions..?

Comment: Well, you probably will have to do it manually, but it is not so hard. You will need to create your scale, i.e. a vector with 255 colors going from blue to white with red in between. Then, just normalize the image as a greyscale image (normalize with limits 0-255) and then create a new image where the values of each pixel is the value of the scale vector with the index of the value of the pixel of the greyscale image. you can take a look to the available [colormaps](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/colormaps.html) I think Jet is close to what you want, without white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a grayscale image (with values 0-255) you can use the [`cv::applyColorMap()`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html) function together with a color-map image (a 1x256 color image) to generate such images.